# Regex for City, State

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to do something relatively simple.  I just want to setup an HTML5 pattern for City, State.  For some reason, this REGEX alludes me.

What am I doing wrong?

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(,[ A-Z]+){200,3}$  (City, State)
```

Comment: `{200,3}` --- what's this? "to setup an HTML5 pattern" --- how is it relevant to `php` then?

Comment: Your right, Its an HTML5 Pattern.  I later explode the string into two separate variables with PHP.

Comment: "I later explode the string into two separate variables with PHP" --- and you're using a microsoft mouse - let's add `microsoft` tag then?

Comment: Actually Razer, but fair enough.  One to many tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are setting a min length inferior to max length here, it should be `{3,200}`.
2. I'll assume what you want is to constraint the **State** length from 3 to 200.
3. You might want to capture the **City** too, so I made you a group, and **skipped the comma**.

**So here is how the regex looks like now**

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)(?:,([ A-Z]{3,200}))$
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to add space to City

```
^([a-zA-Z ]+)(?:,([ A-Z]{3,200}))$
```

Comment: This is almost perfect.  I just had to remove the / / in the beginning and the end, but I'm having an issue with New York, NY or City with Spaces.  I added the space, but nothing yet... ^([a-zA-Z]+)(\\s+)(?:,([ A-Z]{3,200}))$

Comment: I updated my answer but note that you will have to `trim` City and State, because it could have extra space at the beginning or the end (i.e. " New York, CITY ")

Comment: I had to check, but yes, I do.  Thank you very much.  This works perfectly. I even tried adding in the space, but I guess I was way off.